# Execute a method when scrollIntoView ends

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an application in which I want to block the scroll after performing a scrollIntoView, what logic should I use to do it?.
I am using Angular 9.

```
clickCard(){
document.querySelector('.title').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
this.blockScroll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is no method with callback after scrolling ends, nor argument that specify for how long scrolling will be executed. Thus, I see 2 ways of handling it:

1. Use polling. Just checking if the element is in view every N ms. But it be better and help your page responsiveness if you use `window.requestAnimationFrame`(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame )
2. Don't use native scrolling and just scroll page by code. For that you can use some existing library (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-to-element). Or even implement it yourself, it isn't that hard.
   In that way, you will be able to have callback or you could just execute your logic after time that is required to scroll.